# Are there any WebRTC server libraries that provide authentication/hooks-for-it

Tags: webrtc

From what I can see, many WebRTC libraries allow you to verify your own identity by providing an id yourself. Are there any libraries that provide hooks for authentication and only allow the server to identity a client? Is there a preferred open source solution? Do any libraries go a step further and only allow certain connections to be initiated?

Ty!

Comment: question is very unclear. A given ID is very vague

Comment: In order to communicate with another host, it must identify itself somehow. I’m asking are there any WebRTC libraries that completely manage that identification process for the client. For example PeerJS allows you to provide your own clientId as do similar libraries.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-identity/#identity-examples

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-identity/#sec.identity-verify-assertion

Comment: Thank you for the links. Do you know if any stable WebRTC libraries wrap this piece as well?

Comment: I don't think any library has this. But it's simple to implement yourself

Comment: I just want to verify their identity with my own node express server. Can you provide an example of that

Comment: Is this even webrtc related or just sockets?

Comment: WebRTC but I would have a central server just to communicate new connections and authenticate that they can use the server to initiate new WebRTC connections

Comment: So client a would message server b asking client c to create a connection only if a is permitted to, etc. And I can only claim to be some-id on the server if it actually is. I was hoping there was a library to wrap this

Comment: The thing is that the webrtc protocol doesn't even interact with the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220634/discussion-between-dirk-v-and-rubixibuc).